# shared preference edittext settext eror

Tags: java, android

Java codes

```
private void sharedpreferenceAl() {

  SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("geri", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  git.setText(String.valueOf(sp.getInt("salak", 1)));

}



private void sharedpreferencekaydet() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("geri", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sp.edit();
    prefEditor.putString("salak", git.getText().toString());
    prefEditor.commit();
    Log.i("tago", "aaaaaaaaaaa");
    gitbak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        sharedpreferenceAl();

    }

});
```

LOG CAT

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:239)
at kporejct_replics.sunnetler.MainActivity.sharedpreferenceAl(MainActivity.java:123)
at kporejct_replics.sunnetler.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:23)
at kporejct_replics.sunnetler.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:102)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19761)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 2):

change below line -

```
git.setText(String.valueOf(sp.getInt("salak", 1)));
```

to -

```
git.setText(sp.getString("salak", "1"));
```

Comment: Thanks bro i will do

Answer (score 0):

You are putting key as **salak** as **`String`** and getting it as **`Int`**
Just change

```
sp.getInt("salak", 1))
```

to

```
sp.getString("salak", 1)
```

or

just change to

```
 git.setText(sp.getString("salak", 1));
```